# Another way to check the options of a parameter in PHP

Tags: php, enums

I wonder if there is another way of checking a passed string parameter. Currently I do it with an array list that contains all valid options. For this I use the in_array function.

```php
Class Foo {

  private $allowedOptions = ['a','b','c'];

  public function baz(string $parameter): array
  {  
    if (!in_array($parameter, $this->allowedOptions))
    {
      return [];
    }
    
    return doSomething($parameter);
  }
}
```

An idea: Is it also possible to work with Enum?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with enum, then you can type-hint `$parameter` with enum-type.

Comment: @u_mulder Thank you for your comment. Would that be a good approach or would this be too much overhead? Could you please post an example if you have time? Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Define an **Enum** to represent your options:

```
enum Option: string {
    case A = 'a';
    case B = 'b';
    case C = 'c';
}
```

Then update your class to use this **Enum**:

```
class Foo {

    public function baz(string $parameter): array {  
        // you can chekc here if the parameter is a valid Enum case
        if (!Option::tryFrom($parameter)) {
            return [];
        }
        
        return $this->doSomething($parameter);
    }

}
```

`Option::tryFrom($parameter)` will check if the passed `$parameter` is a valid case of the **Option Enum**. If `$parameter` is invalid, function will return an empty array. Otherwise, it will execute your `doSomething` method.

Comment: Why not `public function baz(Option $parameter): array {`?

Comment: Both will work. But you are absolutely correct. Using the enum Option directly as the type for the $parameter argument is a better approach. It ensures type safety.

Comment: @u_mulder additional note: this will require that the calling code passes an Option enum value, like: $resultA = $foo->baz(Option::A);

Comment: @u_mulder Would it also be an advantage to do it like this: `baz(option $parameter)`that Vscode or PHP stream gets the possible options displayed when calling the function baz()?